# How to receive dynamic data from vuex state into component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to learn vuex but I think I am missing some basic understanding. Any advice please.

From one component I am dispatching the scale value of my zoomable map to vuex store.

Store.js

```
export default new Vuex.Store({

    state: {
        scale:""
      },

    getters:{
       MJERILO: state => {
          return state.scale
        }
      },

     mutations:{
        STORESCALE: (state, payload) => {
          state.scale = payload  
        }
      },

      actions:{  
        RECEIVECURRENTSCALE: (context, payload) => {
          context.commit("STORESCALE", payload);
        }
      }    
})
```

This part is working well because in vue dev tool I can see that the scale number is changing in mutation, state and getters when I do zoom in/out with my mouse. (Do, in mutation is changing automaticaly, and for state and getters I need to press load state. I guess this work like this)

So the problem is probably in the way how I am trying to receive data from vuex state into some other component.

I tried:

Map1.vue

```
mounted(){
   var scale = this.$store.getters.MJERILO
}
```

But I just get the value stored in state property mjerilo (in this case empty). And I need dynamic that I sent to state.
For static data this worked perfectly (I tried with simple array).

I also tried to retry data in computed, but I have a similar problem. In this case in mounted I get just the first scale value

```
computed: {
  mjerilo(){
     return this.$store.getters.MJERILO
    }
}

mounted(){
  var scale = this.mjerilo
}
```

I am quite lost. From readings I understand that when ever I scroll my map with mouse I am sending data to action for "registration", than through mutation I am storing this data in state. From state I can get the last updated data (in this case scale) in any other vue component of my app?

**UPDATE: I am adding Map1.vue component**

```
<template>
  <svg-map name="Zupanije" ></svg-map>  
</template>
<script>
import * as d3 from 'd3'
import SvgMap from "./SvgMap"
export default {
    name: "Map1",

    components: {
        "svg-map":SvgMap
    },
    mounted(){
        ......lots of javascrip code
        .
        .
        var scale = this.$store.getters.MJERILO
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please post your complete map component?

Comment: Have you tried using `this.$store.state.scale`?

Comment: @KarloRodriguezDelaRosa yes, I did, still the same problem

Comment: @anpel I updated of my question, so you can see Map1 component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for a function like `watch`

```
data: {
    scale: this.$state.scale
},
watch: {
    '$store.state.scale': (newVal) => {
        this.scale = newVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, with watch I menage to list all my scales. Thank you for pointing me to learn about watch. I have one additional question. From watch I menaged to put scale values in data property and do console.log in watch, but I can not use this data in mounted?

Comment: Hi, you can read [VueJS lifecycle hook](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/vuejs-lifecycle-hooks-7ddf74732b38)  so you can understand how mounted works as well as the others

Comment: can you help me with one more thing. In every explained example I found watch syntax as watch:{ someName: function(){....}} and then I can use watched someName elswhere....but in your example you  use '$store.state.scale'? I understand what it is but I don't get how to use that enywhere else.

Comment: @Kaloy nice one boss kaloy, lakas!!! +1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's wrong but you could try this, what happens then? How you dispatch your action?

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ MJERILO }}
    </div>
</template>


import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";
export default {
    ...mapGetters(["MJERILO"]),
}
```

Comment: The result is the same, just the first scale value. In SvgMap component I define pan zoom using d3.zoom()...so inside zoomed function I reach the scale and dispatch it
var scale = transform.k;
this.$store.dispatch("STORESCALE", scale)